# Yii passing data back into a model

Tags: php, yii

I have been working with Yii for the past few months, but I hit a bit of a block:

In my base controller I have a property `public $currentUserOrganisations = NULL;` which on load populates it with all the logged in users organizations.

Now I have a page where I get all of the organizations and the user can connect to them, but the ones I already have must say "Connected" rather then have the ability to add. I am using the bootstrap `TbGridView` widget and in my `Organisation` model created a function `getConnectionAction` which either returns the anchor OR a label depending if the organization is already connected to the user.

Here is my problem: I can't find a way to access the already loaded user organizations in the `Organisation` model, because it is a property on my model class.

See below for code:

**Action in controller**

```
public function actionNew()
    {
        $connectionModel = Connection::model();
        $organizationModel = Organisation::model();
        $this->selectedSubnav = "Add";
        $this->render('new', array("connectionModel" => $connectionModel, "organizationModel" => $organizationModel));
    }
```

Here is the TbGridView in the view:

```
<?php 
$this->widget(
        'bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',
        array(
            'type'=>'striped',
            'enableSorting'=>true,
            'id' => 'connection-rest-data',
            'dataProvider' => $organizationModel->getConnectionsByOrganization($this->currentOrganisation->id),
            'ajaxUpdate' => true,
            'template'=>"{pager}<br>\n{items}\n{pager}",
            'rowHtmlOptionsExpression' => '',
            'emptyText' => Yii::t("site", "no_restults_found") . '.',
            "itemsCssClass" => "table table-first-column-number data-table display full dataTable transaction_tbl",
            'columns' => array(
                array(
                    'header' => Yii::t("site", "id"),
                    'value' => '$data->id',
                    'type' => 'raw',
                    'name' => 'id'
                ),
                array(
                    'header' => Yii::t("site", "from_unit"),
                    'type' => 'raw',
                    'value' => '$data->fromUnit["name"]',
                    'name' => 'fromUnit'
                ),
                array(
                    'header' => Yii::t("site", "to_unit"),
                    'type' => 'raw',
                    'value' => '$data->toUnit["name"]',
                    'name' => 'type'
                ),
                array(
                    'header' => Yii::t("site", "connection_type"),
                    'type' => 'raw',
                    'value' => '$data->type["name"]',
                    'name' => 'type'
                ),
                array(
                    'header' => Yii::t("site", "ended"),
                    'type' => 'raw',
                    'value' => '$data->ended',
                    'name' => 'ended'
                ),
                array(
                    'header' => Yii::t("site", "fees"),
                    'type' => 'raw',
                    'value' => 'empty($data->fees) ? "none" :  $data->fees["fee"]',
                    'name' => 'fees'
                ),
                array(
                    'header' => Yii::t("site", "actions"),
                    'type' => 'raw',
                    'value' => 'Organisation::model()->getConnectionAction($data->id, \'' . serialize($this->currentUserOrganisations) . '\'")',
                    'name' => 'fees'
                )
            ),
        )
    );
?>
```

And here is the function in the `Organisations` Model:

```
public function getConnectionAction ($connectionId)
    {
        $currentOrganizations = null; //This I need to get the public $currentUserOrganisations = NULL; value
        foreach ($currentOrganizations as $org)
        {
            if($org->id == $connectionId)
            {
                return CHtml::label(Yii::t("site", "connected"), "", array("style" => "color:green;"));
            }
        }
        return CHtml::link("Add", "/connection/manage/addConnection?id=$connectionId");
    }
```

Much appreciated guys and give me a shout if anything is unclear!

Comment: $currentOrganizations does not belong to controller, but to the model, so just move it there.

Comment: It belongs to the user actually, all organizations belonging to the user which is on every page, that is why we set it in the base controller

Comment: Why not use user()->currentOrganizations then?

Comment: Because then foreach result I would query the server and get it again...

Comment: Your `getConnectionAction` method is not going to do anything except the `CHtml::Link` because `$currentOrganizations` will always be `null` when it gets to the `foreach`, and that loop will therefore be skipped every time.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy Have you read the post above or the comment next to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I managed a work around which is very close to what Martin said.

In the view for the specific field I do:

`'value' => 'Organisation::model()->getConnectionAction($data->id, ' . $this->currentOrganisation->id . ')',`

The id is the id of the listed organization and the currentOrganization->id is the id of the users current organization.

Then in my model I get all the organizations for the user:

`$currentOrganizations = $this->findAllForUserByOrganizationId($currentOrgId);`

Foreach through them and check if they match, full function below.

```
public function getConnectionAction ($organizationId, $currentOrgId)
    {
        $currentOrganizations = $this->findAllForUserByOrganizationId($currentOrgId);
        foreach ($currentOrganizations as $org)
        {
            if(in_array($organizationId, array($org->fromUnit['id'], $org->toUnit['id'])))
            {
                return CHtml::label(Yii::t("site", "connected"), "", array("style" => "color:green;"));
            }
        }
        return CHtml::link(Yii::t("site", "add_connection"), "/connection/manage/addConnection?id=$connectionId", array("class" => "createConnection"));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are going to want to avoid Active Record for this one. You can use a [CSqlDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSqlDataProvider) to load your `TbGridView`.  Use SQL that looks something like this

```
select 
   org.organization_name,
   user.name
from organization org
   left outer join connection x on org.id = x.organization_id
   join user on user.id = x.user_id
where user.id = ? or user.id is null
```

That ? is a parameter marker to allow you to pass in a user_id in a parameter array rather than just concatenating it.  Concatenation provides an opening for SQL injection.

Then in your column list for the gid view test the user.name for null and if null display the add button.  If not null, display connected.

Comment: Not going to work, it is from a DB but from a api which we have an ActiveRecord adpater, https://github.com/Haensel/ActiveResource